# Script language used by Birkhoff

Tags: nikita

Which scripting language does Seymour Birkhoff use to communicate with his father in Nikita season 4?

Comment: Picture or write it out please

Answer (score 1):

Season 4, Episode 3, "Set-Up". The scene is where Birkhoff is pretending to find a mole at the NSA for the benefit of the double who took his father's place. At the other end of the connection, his real father is monitoring, and Birkhoff uses this to surreptitiously communicate with him.

The code snippet shown on screen and repeated over and over again as it's scrolling appears to be PHP code utilizing a mysql database to determine rights assigned to a user.

[image: Code segment from Nikita 4x3 "Set-Up"]

It appears that the code may have come from a forum post here:
http://forum.phpfrance.com/php-avance/conseils-niveaux-utilisateur-t259943.html